# How to return object instead of string for response with nock?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, fakeweb, nock

When I stub request with [`nock`](https://github.com/pgte/nock) it returns `String` result instead of `Object` even with `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`:

```
var response = {
  success: true,
  statusCode: 200,
  body: {
    "status": "OK",
    "id": "05056b27b82",
  }
};

Test.BuildRequest();
Test.SendRequest(done);

nock('https://someapi.com')
  // also tried
  // .defaultReplyHeaders({
  //   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  //   'Accept': 'application/json'
  // })

  .post('/order')
  .reply(200, response.body, 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json');
```

checking:

```
console.log(put.response.body);
console.log(put.response.body.id);
```

output:

```
{"status":"OK","id":"05056b27b82"}
undefined
```

In code I use `request` module that returns `Object` with the same data. I tried also `sinon` (doesn't work for me) and `fakeweb` but got the same issue.

**My code**, which i'm trying to test:

```
var request = require('request');
// ...

request(section.request, function (err, response, body) {
  if (err || _.isEmpty(response))
    return result(err, curSyndication);

  //if (_.isString(body))
  //    body = JSON.parse(body);

  section.response.body = body;
  console.log(body.id); // => undefined (if uncomment previous code - 05056b27b82)

  _this.handleResponse(section, response, body, result);
});
```

And it returns an object in real requests.

**PS**. I could add next code in my response handler:

```
if (_.isString(body))
  body = JSON.parse(body);
```

But some of queries returns xml string, and i'm not responsible for such changes.

**Fakeweb**:

```
fakeweb.registerUri({
  uri: 'https://someapi.com/order',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    status: "OK",
    id: "05056b27b82",
  }),
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'My requestor',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
});
Test.SendRequest(done);
```

Same results.

**Updated:**

I read a couple of articles, that uses JSON Object, without parsing it (with nock), so it should returns JSON object, same way how request library do that.

Comment: nock returns JSON. To convert to Object you need to convert the JSON to Object using `JSON.parse` --> http://jsfiddle.net/5qaxtfz6/

Comment: I updated my answer. [Request](https://github.com/request/request) module returns an Object

Comment: In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689252/how-can-superagent-and-nock-work-together) it returns an Object.

Comment: Have you specified the `json` option on your `section.request` object? So do you have `section.request.json = true` somewhere in your code? Because it is need for `request` to "additionally, parses the response body as JSON."

Comment: That solves my problem, thanks! You can post the answer for awards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your nock configuration however you haven't told `request` to parse the response as JSON.

From the [`request` method](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) documentation (emphasis on me):

> `json` - sets body but to JSON representation of value and adds Content-type: application/json header. **Additionally, parses the response body as JSON.**
>
> The callback argument gets 3 arguments:
>
> - An error when applicable (usually from http.ClientRequest object)
> - An http.IncomingMessage object
> - The third is the response body (String or Buffer, or **JSON object if the `json` option is supplied**)

So you need to set the `json` property to `true` on your `section.request` object:

```
var request = require('request');
// ...

section.request.json = true;
request(section.request, function (err, response, body) {
  //..
});
```

Comment: Thanks for complete answer, i'll award a bounty when it'll be enabled.